# How not to count middle white pages in page numbering?

Tags: page-numbering

In my document, I have some white pages that I don't want to be counted in page numbering. What should I do?

```
%pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\lipsum[5-8]
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\lipsum[9-12]
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\lipsum[13-16]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are these white pages in the middle of the document or at the start?

Comment: In the middle. @1010011010

Comment: What would you like a PDF viewer to show for a page number when you're on the page without a page number? And what about after?

Comment: I don't want that white page to be counted (the page before white be x and the page after be x+1 numbered) and in PDF viewer total number of pages, the white pages also not to be counted.

Comment: Maybe a combination of `\thispagestyle{empty}` and `\addtocounter{page}{-1}`?

Comment: Do you add these white pages manually or they are added by commands like `\chapter` based on document class that you are using?

Comment: Well, if you're going to mess up the fact that odd page is on the right when you open the document, simply don't use `twoside` at all. It's a complete non-sense. It would be really nice to get a MWE.

Comment: @Pouya I add these white pages by the following command. `\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage`

Comment: @tohecz I have to use two-sided style because of the thesis format. But adding too many white pages resulted exceeding the allowed number of pages. I have 20 white pages which should not be numbered and counted and even calculated in the final pdf's total number of pages. I edited the question to show a MWE.

Comment: And have you thought of `openany` option to the `report` or `book` class? Or changing some chapters to sections, because if you have 20 empty pages, it suggests that you have much more than 20 chapters, which seems to be simply too much for (even a long) thesis.

Comment: @tohecz no... what do you mean?

Comment: **Where do the empty pages come from?** That is the critical question. Once you answer it, I may be better able to explain you what I am after.

Comment: @tohecz I added those emty pages to bring the chapters on the right side odd numbered pages. And, my thesis is 155 pages and I want to bring it under 150 by omitting those white pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18002/discussion-between-tohecz-and-enthusiastic-student).

Answer (score 3):

As per the comment, you can use `\addtopagecounter{page}{-1}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}\newpage
\lipsum[5-8]
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}\newpage
\lipsum[9-12]
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}\newpage
\lipsum[13-16]
\end{document}
```

If you want to do it for all the `\thispagestyle{empty}` pages you can save some typing with a custom macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\eatpage}{\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\newpage\null\eatpage\newpage
\lipsum[5-8]
\newpage\null\eatpage\newpage
\lipsum[9-12]
\newpage\null\eatpage\newpage
\lipsum[13-16]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the numbering problem. Can I do anything with the PDF file problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the PDF file problem?

Comment: I don't want the white pages, also be calculated in total number of pages in the pdf file...

Comment: So isn't it easier to change your document so that it does not produce the white pages at all?

Comment: `\addtopagecounter` ?